# ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-core

I am trying to test CMUSphinx voice recignition engine upon Ubuntu-core 16.04. But I get this Error messages:

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Error opening audio device default for capture: Connection refused
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device
```

I did test it before with Debian Jessie successfully. But Ubuntu core gives me this Error!